# inputLocalFont.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a code for add images with php and js, but I have error on my js and it's says

> inputLocalFont.addEventListener is not a function

This is my code:

```
<div>
    <img src="<?php echo $img_path.'/'.$img_name ?>" width="400px" height="400px"/>
    <ul class="add_img_ul">
        <li class="subimg"><input type="file" class="file" name="file"/><img id="add" src="icons/add.jpg" width="80px" height="80px"/></li>
    </ul>                       
    <script>
        var inputLocalFont = document.getElementsByClassName("file");
        inputLocalFont.addEventListener("change",previewImages,false);

            function previewImages(){
                var fileList = this.files;

                var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

                    for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
                         var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
                            $('.add_img_ul').append('<input type="file" class="file" name="file"/><img src="' + objectUrl + '" width="80px" height="80px"/>');
                            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
                    }   
             }          
     </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName`, as the name implies, returns a *collection* of elements, not just one element. If you want the first element from the collection, index into it with index 0 (`[0]`).

```
var inputLocalFont = document.getElementsByClassName("file");
inputLocalFont[0].addEventListener("change",previewImages,false);
// -----------^^^
```

But if you really just want the first, there's no reason to get a list: `querySelector` will give you the first match for any CSS selector:

```
var inputLocalFont = document.querySelector(".file");
inputLocalFont.addEventListener("change",previewImages,false);
```

...and it has the advantage that it works on IE8 (and all modern browsers), whereas `getElementsByClassName` doesn't work on IE8. For times you do want a list, `querySelectorAll` is available as well.